# Meaning of 他希望自己的知識面能更加寬闊

Tags: meaning

他希望自己的知識**面**能更加寬闊

What does 面 mean here? It seems unnecessary because 他希望自己的知識能更加寬闊 is much more clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, 面 shall be interpreted as "dimension".

More formally, the sentence should be "他希望自己的知識**層面**能更加寬闊". "層面" is a word for "范围" or "领域" in Chinese, and "aspect" or "level" in English, so the person is wishing to diverse/broaden his knowledge base.

Answer (score 2):

知识面: range or scope of knowledge

他一向主张大学生的知识面要宽一些。
He has always been of the opinion that university students ought to have a wider range of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

知识面 means 智力成果的范围 scope of knowledge, use wide or narrow to describe it.
But I didn't find one answer for sure, so I show all my thought in the following.

1. 面 is 方面 (aspect), 宽阔 means wide. 知识面宽阔 means someone knows many different aspects/kinds of knowledge, such as biology, geography, literature, art and so on.
2. 面 is 平面 (plane) can also help you understand that. Imagine knowledge as a plane, so the more knowledge you have, the wider this "plane" will be in terms of area. I feel this description just like "broaden your horizon"…

Without 面， your sentence is not about width in the area, but quantity.
You can use 他希望自己的知識能更加**丰富**.

丰富 means rich, to emphasis on the quantity of knowledge. “enrich one’s knowledge"

Hope this can help :)